# Getting script exec time

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, sh

I am trying to find out script execution time using the following bash script

```
start=$(date +%s.%N) # run time
# code to execute script
end=$(date +%s.%N) # end time
printf '\n"total_time":' "$((start-end))"
```

But getting the following error from `printf` statement

```
syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".064560120")
```

I also want to include word `s` or `ms` in the output

Comment: Do you know *time*? `time command`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash doesn't do floating point arithmetic. You'll have to use some other shell, or call an external program, like `bc`.

```
$ a=$(date +%s.%N); sleep .4; b=$(date +%s.%N)
$ diff=$(echo "$b - $a" | bc -l)
$ printf "runtime: %0.3f seconds\n" "$diff"
runtime: 0.403 seconds
```

(`%s` on the printf would print the raw output of `bc`.)

In zsh, for example, it works straight in the shell:

```
$ zsh -c 'a=$(date +%s.%N); sleep .4; b=$(date +%s.%N); echo "runtime: $(( b - a ))" seconds'
runtime: 0.40290713310241699 seconds
```

See also: [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/170373) over at Unix.SE.

Comment: can you let me know how the `printf` will look like in this case? `printf '\n "runtime: "$b - $a" | bc -l ` is giving an error

Comment: @all_techie, wrap the call to `bc` in a command substitution `$(...)` to capture the output. Example edited.